# Finding the the derivative of $y=\sqrt{1-\sin x}; 0<x<\pi/2$.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

A question I'm attempting is:

> Find the derivative of $ y = \sqrt {1 - \sin x} ; 0 < x <\pi/2$.

I did this:
$y = \sqrt {1 - \sin x} = \sqrt {\cos^2\frac{x}{2} + \sin^2\frac{x}{2} - 2\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos \frac{x}{2}} = \sqrt { (\sin \frac{x}{2}-\cos \frac{x}{2})^2} = \sin \frac{x}{2} - \cos \frac{x}{2}$

So,  $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (\cos\frac{x}{2} + \sin\frac{x}{2})$.

But apparently this is wrong. The correct solution is:
$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{2}\cdot(\cos\frac{x}{2} + \sin\frac{x}{2})$.

So I want to know what I have done wrongly here. Why is my answer not right?

Comment: note that $(a-b)^2=(b-a)^2$

Comment: @MathLover Yes I am aware of that. But the problem given above is a part of another and so we have to simplify it.

Comment: in addition to Vasya's comment note that $\sqrt{u^2}=|u|$.

Comment: I don't know who is downvoting all the answers here but it is not me. I have upvoted those ones here that completely answer my question. Downvoter, the answers provided don't deserve to be downvoted so please remove the downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $y = |\sin(x/2)-\cos(x/2)|$  and $|\sin(x/2)-\cos(x/2)|=\color{red}{-}(\sin(x/2)-\cos(x/2))$ for $0 \le x \le \pi/2$.

Comment: Oh okay. So, since if we choose $\sin x/2 - \cos x/2$ the expression inside square root sign becomes negative and overall expression becomes a complex number, which is not allowed here; so we choose $\cos x/2 - \sin x/2$. Am I right?

Comment: @MrReality No, the expression inside the square root does not become negative. Rather, $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$. For example, $\sqrt{(-4)^2} = |-4| = +4$.

Comment: Okay. I understand now. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Let apply chain rule

$$\left( \sqrt{f(x)} \right)'=\frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}}=\frac{-\cos x}{2\sqrt {1 - \sin x}}=\frac12\frac{\sin^2 x/2-\cos^2 x/2}{(\cos x/2-\sin x/2)}=\\=\frac12\frac{ (\sin x/2+\cos x/2)(\sin x/2-\cos x/2) }{(\cos x/2 - \sin x/2)}=-\frac12(\sin x/2+\cos x/2)$$

Note indeed that for $0<x<\pi/2$ since

- $\cos x/2 >0$
- $0<\tan x/2<1$

$$\cos x/2-\sin x/2=\cos x/2\cdot(1-\tan x/2)>0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y = \sqrt {1 - \sin x} ; 0 < x <\pi/2$$

$$ y' = \frac {-\cos x}{2 \sqrt {1 - \sin x}}$$

$$=\frac {-\cos x\sqrt {1 + \sin x  }}{2 \cos x}$$

$$=-\frac {\sqrt {1 + \sin x}}{2}=-\frac12(\sin x/2+\cos x/2)$$

Note that $$(\sin x/2+\cos x/2)^2=1+2\sin x/2\cos x/2=1+\sin x$$

Answer (score 0):

An option:

$y^2 = 1-\sin x$; $0\lt x\lt π/2.$

Differentiate both sides with respect to x:

$2y\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\cos x;$

Since $y \not =0:$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\dfrac{\cos x}{2\sqrt{1-\sin x}}$.

Comment: The asker is interested in this particular simplification of the derivative.

Comment: Gimusi.Yes.The OP has been given a few  pertinent answers .Hence I called it an option. From.here you can, if you wish,  'simplify'.

Comment: it's  a very good option indeed!

Comment: GimusiYou are something!! Good. to have you around.:))

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\sqrt {1-\sin x}$$
$$\ln y= \frac 12 \cdot \ln (1-\sin x)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac 1y \frac {dy}{dx}=\frac 12\left (\frac {-\cos x}{1-\sin x}\right) $$
$$\Rightarrow \frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {-\cos x}{2\sqrt {1-\sin x}}$$
On rationalisation of denominator this turns out to be $$-\frac 12 (\sin x/2 +\cos x/2)$$